# Oauth2 samples not working because dependency error

Tags: java, maven, oauth-2.0

I have downloaded [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) Maven project from GitHub with the samples `tonr2` and `spaklr2`.

I have been continously getting an error message in `pom.xml` after all the jar files are finished downloaded.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

It is showing an error in this below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The error is:

> Missing artifact org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

After run the command

```
mvn install -P bootstrap
```

I got the next error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project spring-security-oauth2: There are test failu
res.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\a.bazaldua.cerda\Desktop\Oauth\spring-security-
oauth-master\spring-security-oauth2\target\surefire-reports for the individual t
est results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

Comment: What Maven command did you ran?

Comment: I have the project in eclipse, so first I clean up the project, later I make a maven upgrade...  and after that I make maven clean and maven install.... but the error is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) project, you first need to run the following command:

```
mvn clean install -P bootstrap -DskipTests=true
```

You can run it directly on the command line (it is the easy solution).

If you want to do this directly in Eclipse, you will need to create a custom Maven Build. Go into "Run > Run Configurations...". Double-click "Maven Build" to create a new custom Maven build. Give it a name, select the base directory to the working directory of the project you are trying to build, select the goals "clean install" and the profiles "bootstrap".

After the first build is done, update the Maven project in Eclipse and you will no longer have any errors.

Comment: Man I just make the command after delete all .m2 folder but seems to have an error... I update the post.